# Git cheat sheet

Tags: git

I come from SVN and decided to use GIT now for a project of mine.
I have seen Mercurial cheat sheet, and GIT tutorials but not suggestion to a nice and clean GIT sheet.
Is there a GIT cheat sheet that is a good balance between thorough explanation of commands and brevity?
Thank you.

Comment: Git is still evolving, so the cheat sheets you'll find online might be outdated. Moreover, many of those are merely scratching the surface given Git's large number of commands and possible workflows...

Comment: Thanks, I understand your point. But nonetheless there are some commands that are well established. Especially for a beginner, it could be very useful to have a nice cheat sheet that increases the speed of the learning curve...

Comment: So bad that someone though this is not a valid question.
[a simple review of search results says the opposite](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cheat+sheet)

Comment: I think people downvote/vote to close this question because every answer might promote a different solution based on personal preference, so there is no reason for a specific answer to be the 'good' one. It is probably hard to determine a "good" cheat sheet based on facts alone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type in google `github cheat sheet ext:pdf`. First 3 results are realy not bad.

Anyway you can find nice [help](https://help.github.com/) on github site

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [Git SVN crash course](http://git.or.cz/course/svn.html) - a guide especially made for people switching from SVN to Git.

Comment: +1 for the nice guide, but this is exactly what I tried to avoid. I am really keen at this stage about cheat sheet.

Answer (score 1):

I find that [this one](http://ndpsoftware.com/git-cheatsheet.html) is sometime useful as a bookmark. If you need a start point for use git i recommend two resources:

- [github start tutorial](http://try.github.com/levels/1/challenges/1)
- [git ready](http://gitready.com/) This one have pointers to another two really good sources of information: [git book](http://git-scm.com/book) and [git from botton up](http://newartisans.com/2008/04/git-from-the-bottom-up/).

Answer (score 0):

One of the best Git Cheat Sheets ever by Matthew McCullough [right here](http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/getting-started-git).